# Add click-amount to element via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ul-list with an unpredictable amount of li-elements (anything between 2 and 8).
I wanna use these li-elements to catch a vote and display the amount of votes on the clicked element itself. I would use something like that to catch the clicks:

```
$('#result li').click(function() {
$('#result li').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});
```

But how would I then need to structure my html to identify which element did get clicked?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the click events context to get `this` which is the individual element. You can either use the node directly or convert to a JQuery element `$(this)`.

If you are then wanting to track each elements click you can bind to its context and set its clicked value.

```
$('#result li').click(function(){
    this.clicked = this.clicked ? this.clicked + 1 : 1;
    $(this).html(this.clicked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/su14hjc0/

This means you can also reference the clicked value in other places.

```
console.log($('#result li:eq(1)')[0].clicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$(this)](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/):

```
$('#result li').click(function() {
    $(this).html('I am clicked'); // of course, set the proper value here
});
```

---

See here:

```js
    $('#result li').click(function() {
        $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html(), 10) + 1);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="result">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>88</li>
  </ul>
```